# Ajax not working when fn() placed in external file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have problems with Ajax because as long as the function is placed in an external file, the code wont run, but if I put the `<script>` tags inside the file it runs with no problems. Here is the function:

```
function show_version(str) {
    var xmlhttp;    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {document.getElementById("sver").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
    }   

    xmlhttp.open("GET","version.php?sname="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have already tested `version.php` and works perfectly fine. This is what I'm using to call the file:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/search/jsSearch.js"></script>`
A quick recap:
If i use the `<script>` tags inside the file, the function works perfectly, but if I try to link the file externally, it just does nothing at all.

I've tried looking on Ajax tutorials on w3schools.com but I couldn't find anything regarding this issue. Do you know where else I should look into?

Comment: What does the script tag look like that imports the external file?

Comment: Are you seeing any JS errors?  Where are you including the script tag within your HTML? Before or after the element with id="ever"? How is show_version() triggered?

Answer (score 1):

do you have jQuery running on your external scripts page with a document ready function?

I had the same issue when trying to run ajax on my page. Worked fine when the ajax script was added inline to my page but when I moved it to an external script page it no longer worked.

After looking at my code I realized that I accidentally placed that ajax function inside my document ready function, which I was using for some other jQuery coding. After I moved it out of the document ready function everything worked perfect again. Simple fix but could be your issue